# type number and pattern not showing error label

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to have a field in which users can type only numbers 0-9. In case they type other characters like '.' or 'e' it has to show an error that only positive natural numbers are allowed. Form is used in Angular.

So I have here the html form:

```
<div class="col-xl-8">
  <input  formControlName="money" type="number" class="form-control">
  <span class="error" *ngIf="money?.errors?.pattern"> Natural numbers </span>
</div>
```

while pattern is

```
this.money = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*$')]);
```

The pattern is just fine it allows numbers from 0 till 9 and it doesn't allow decimals or '.' or 'e'.

So the problem is that since input is type number it allows '.' and 'e' even though the pattern doesn't allow it and I can't submit it, the error message is not showed since the html validater is based on the type number thing.

Yet, inputs such as these are allowed and the error label does not appear:

- 1.....2
- ......
- eeee........
- 1.0.0.01.0
  And so on.

So what should I do to show the error label when '.' or 'e' are typed?

Comment: `<span class="error" *ngIf="yourForm.get('money').hasError('pattern')"> Natural numbers </span>`, can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pattern directive directly?

```
<div class="col-xl-8">
  <input  formControlName="money" 
          type="number"
          ng-pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$')]" 
          class="form-control">
  <span class="error" *ngIf="money?.errors?.pattern"> Natural numbers </span>

</div>
```

And tie validation to `$valid` of that input `myForm.myInput.$valid`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
<div class="col-xl-8">
  <input  [formControl]="money" 
          type="number"
          class="form-control">
  <span class="error" *ngIf="money.dirty && money?.errors?.pattern"> Natural numbers </span>

</div>
```

In your ts file update regex ^[1-9][0-9]{1,3}

Hope it will help

Comment: I have still that problem

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look and let me know it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

> In .ts file :

```
export class ReactiveFormExampleComponent{
   reactiveForm: FormGroup;

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.reactiveForm = fb.group({
            money: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*$')]]
        });
     }

     onSubmit() {
         alert("Form submitted");
     }
}
```

> html file

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" nonvalidate>
  <div>
    <label class="center-block">Money:
          <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="money">
      </label>
      <span [hidden]="reactiveForm.controls.money.valid || reactiveForm.controls.money.pristine" class="errorMsg">Natural numbers only</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="reactiveForm.invalid" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

> NOTE : Don't forget to import 'ReactiveFormsModule' in NgModule.

Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/60L385QVHMI1jp2lexun?p=preview) check it out here.